# Illustrator CS6 rounding corners

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, corners

Im trying to trace a logo with a slight rounded corner.I have on the other corners been using the shapebuilder tool using the eclipse shape to form the corner but this one is so slight I am wondering if there is an easier way? I tried to use the pen tool but it was quite clunky and didn't seem to give me a smooth curve.

Comment: See this video [tutorial](https://youtu.be/OI1aMkb6dFk) on how to create a rounded corners rectangle

Comment: This is kind of impossible to answer. No one here knows what the curve looks like and the pen tool should work in all instances.

Comment: Pen clunky? Now you at least know what skill needs serious sharpening if you are going to actually draw something with reasonable effort in Illustrator. I must admit that the pen hasn't gave to me anything of the numerous talents that I happened to miss in the birth, but it is the tool to draw curves manageably. The pencil and paint brushes need much more finer ability to control the line. Get some tutorials and start practicing today, although yesterday would be better.